# Convergence of the maximum of sums of random variables in probability

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X_i$ be independent random variables. Let $S_{m, n} = X_{m+1} + \cdots +X_n$. Then Levy's theorem says that $$P\left(\max_{m<j\leq n} |S_{m,j}| \geq 2a\right) \min_{m<k\leq n} P(|S_{k,n}| \leq a) \leq P(|S_{m,n}| > a)$$ I am trying to use this result to prove that if $S_n = X_1 + \cdots+X_n$ and $S_n/n \rightarrow 0$ in probability, then also $(\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} S_m) /n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

If we apply Levy's Theorem with $a$ replaced by $an$, we get $$P(\max_{1 \leq m \leq n} |S_m| > 2an) \leq \frac{P(|S_{0,n}| > an)}{\min_{0 < k \leq n} P(|S_{k,n}| \leq an)}$$ Now the numerator goes to $0$ by our assumption, but I don't know what to do with the denominator at all. How can I finish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Cut off the max from below at some large $l$, rather than at $0$. For large enough $l$, the denominator is bounded below by a simple triangle inequality argument.